# FET Practical DC Analysis Problems

Tags: bias, jfet, transconductance

I just finished with theory understanding of FET transistor principles, etc.

Right after that I tried to make simple circuit Common-Source with FET and MOSFET the problems occurred one by another.

I could begin with JFET (n-channel) for start:

- Idss (when Vds = 15V) = 6mA
- Vgss(off) (when Vds = 15V & Id = 10nA) = from -0.5V to -8V
- Different admittances at Vgs = 0 and I don't know which to chose for calculating Id

All I wanted was to bias the FET, so that Vds = Vdd/2, so in the middle of the load line (for the start). Vdd would be 20V and Id would be 5mA > Vds would then be 10V, right?

I can't find appropriate Vgs and also don't know how to connect gate resistor (series or parallel) + I can't calculate its value since gate current cant be calculated and/or is not practically usable (neglected).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7XdE6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Transistor's datasheet: [www.mouser.com/ds/2/149/bf244a-292510.pdf](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/149/bf244a-292510.pdf)

Comment: Vgg will be somewhere between 0 and -8 V to achieve Id = 5 mA. The value needed will vary from device to device. Rgs is not needed as long as Vgg is always negative. Rgs in series with the gate may be desirable to prevent damage in case Vgg goes positive.

Comment: How should I then calculate or pick up the right voltage for known Id, Idss and Vds?

Comment: Also which of these admittances is the admittance when Vgs is zero: Forward transfer admittance, Reverse transfer admittance & Output admittance? If the gm at Vgs = 0 is known and desired drain current also, then the needed Vgs could be calculated, right?

Comment: None, forward transfer admittance should be \$i_d/v_g\$; reverse transfer admittance I'm not sure about but might be \$i_g/v_d\$. Input admittance in typical operating conditions should be roughly \$j\omega C_{iss}\$. Caveat: I do not regularly use JFETs  in the real world, so if somebody contradicts this, believe them ahead of me.

Comment: You won't be able to calculate Vgs for a given Id until you've measured a particular device and found its Vgs(off). And even then you might worry about it changing over temperature. If you want a fixed Id, you probably need to set up a feedback circuit to adjust Vgs according to conditions.

Comment: @ThePhoton: So unipolar transistors are seriously complicated compared to bipolar, when calculating values used for biasing, right?

Comment: JFETs generally need gate voltage outside the voltage range between drain and source,  which might lead to using dual power supplies, if that's what you mean --- part of why they're only used when their other advantages are really needed. But (enhancement-mode) MOSFETs don't have this requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a one or a few JFET's in your disposal you can try to measure them.

You can use this setup:

[image]

AS you can see you can use a voltmeter to measure **Vgs(off)** and ammeter to measure **Idss** at once, all you need is to switch your multimeter between voltmeter/ammeter.

And you know **Vgs(off)** and **Idss** you can solve for **Vgs**:

$$V_{GS} = Vgs(off)* \left(1 - \sqrt{\frac{I_D}{I_{DSS}}} \right)$$

I have two JFET in my workbench
First one is **BF245A** and I measure it and got

**Vgs(off) = - 1.9V** and **Idss = 5mA**

And **BF245C**:

**Vgs(off)= -4.8V** and **Idss = 15mA**

(the typical values given in datasheet are -5.6V/17mA).

So, If I want **Id = 5mA** I would use **BF245C**.

And **Rd = 10V/5mA = 2.2kΩ**

$$g_{m0} = \frac{2*I_{DSS}}{|V_{GS}(off)|} = \frac{30mA}{4.8V} = 6.25mS$$

Therefore the maximum gain passible for a given drain resistor is
\$R_D = 2.2kΩ\$ is:

\$Av = g_{m0}R_D = 13.75 \; V/V\$ (without Rs)

For automatic bias you now need to select \$R_S\$ resistor

$$V_{GS} = Vgs(off)* \left(1 - \sqrt{\frac{I_D}{I_{DSS}}} \right) = -4.8V*\left(1 - \sqrt{\frac{5mA}{15mA}} \right) = -2V $$

$$R_S  = \frac{2V}{5mA} = 400Ω = 390Ω$$

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNziPz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

And now we can test the circuit on the workbench.

Comment: Great! The only thing that disturbs me is that Vgs(off) needs to be actually measured for a designer to have an accurate value.

Comment: @Keno This is why we almost never use a single stage amplifier. We are forced to use a more advanced circuit with negative feedback.  Here you have the example http://obrazki.elektroda.net/18_1263575503.jpg