# Multisim virtual JFET saturation current

Tags: amplifier, jfet, multisim

How I can set virtual JFET saturation current in Multisim. I can't find any parameter with appropriate name in model settings of virtual JFET?

Comment: Saturation current?

Comment: @G36 Yes, Drain Saturation Current I_DSS

Comment: Idss is set by a JFET model used in the simulation. Red from the simulation the Beta value and Vto. And Idss = Beta*Vto^2 https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/316828/fet-practical-dc-analysis-problems/317588#317588